# convert df into a pairwise distance matrix

Tags: r

I'm using code (not my own) that converts a data frame (`Mol.Info`) of mass spec peaks and associated elemental ratios into a pairwise distance matrix between mass peaks.  The code works beautifully, but I don't understand how it works.  I see that the `row.names = row.names(Mol.Info)` will ensure the new data frame will contain the same row names, but in the hopes of understanding code better, could someone break down the line for me, `apply(Mol.Info, 2, scale)`?

```
# Pairwise distance between peaks
Mol.Info = as.data.frame(apply(Mol.Info, 2, scale), row.names = row.names(Mol.Info))

> dput(head(Mol.Info))
structure(list(C = c(7L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L), H = c(7L, 12L, 
11L, 11L, 7L, 11L), O = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L), N = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L), S = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), P = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DBE = c(5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 4L), AI_Mod = c(0.333333333, 
0, 0.111111111, 0.111111111, 1, 0), kdefect.CH2 = c(0.221048311, 
0.208231648, 0.166968949, 0.16684561, 0.165547015, 0.155639304
)), row.names = c("200.002276", "200.015107", "200.0564158", 
"200.0565393", "200.0578394", "200.0677581"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The `apply` is just calling the function `scale` on each column, then, since the result is a matrix, converting that matrix back into a data frame. Personally, I think `Mol.Info[] <- lapply(Mol.Info, scale)` would be a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your interpretation and input.

Comment: This is just standardizing the data, so that each column has a standard deviation of 1 and mean 0. I don't see anything here that computes pairwise distances, for that the `dist` function can be used. (I agree with Allan's suggestion of a slightly better way to do this.)